# Spark parse string to timestamp with timezone

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp, timezone, timezone-offset

I have a string like:

```
2018-03-21T08:15:00+01:00
```

and wonder how to preserve the time zone / shift from UTC when parsing it in Spark.

```
Seq("2018-03-21T08:15:00+01:00").toDF.select('value, to_timestamp('value, "yyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")).show(false)
```

unfortunately only yields `null`. Even my format string which is omitting the shift only returns `null`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`T` is not a format specifier so it should be escaped:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
```

and timezone is denoted by `X`

```
"yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"
```